# How to disable the photoset in tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr

I wanna disable the photoset and just show one image in the grid box,I used {block:Photos}{/block:Photos} outside img tag, however, it still doesn't work, I don't know why.

Code:

```
  {block:photoset}

               {block:Photos} 
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" border="0" />
               {/block:Photos} 

           {block:Caption}
           <div class="entry">
             <blockquote>{Caption}</blockquote>
           </div>
           {/block:Caption}
         {/block:photoset}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show the first image of a Photoset you'll have to do this:

HTML:

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="my-photoset">
        {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" border="0" />
        {/block:Photos}
    </div>

    {block:Caption}
    <div class="entry">
        <blockquote>{Caption}</blockquote>
    </div>
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

CSS:

```
.my-photoset img {
    display: none;
}

.my-photoset img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

You can change the classes to be whatever you want them to be, I just put those in as an example. There may be classes that you can tie into in the theme already.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site you are trying it on?

Comment: You didn't update the HTML, you are still using {Photoset-500} instead of the code I provided above.

Comment: I do use {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" border="0" />
        {/block:Photos}, however, I found that output is still photoset code.

Comment: If you use the HTML I've posted above, it's *impossible* that Tumblr is outputting an iFrame. Can you post your code up somewhere?