# Tumblr - Disable photoset only for the homepage

Tags: post, tumblr

all i ever wanted is having one single cover photo for each of my post instead of the photoset. I was able to disable the photoset thanks to a topic in this forum [How to disable the photoset in tumblr theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627465/how-to-disable-the-photoset-in-tumblr-theme/21231105?noredirect=1#comment31979684_21231105)

the problem now is:

1) the photoset is disabled also in the post permalink page. I wanted to disable it only for my homepage. 
2) the pictures on my homepage are not linkable anymore, so i can't acces to my post permalink.

my site is www.thewhaleside.tumblr.com i use a normal Optical Grid Theme

i hope somebody can help me with this :(

Comment: thanks for the reply, i don't think it's so complicated...what i would like to achieve is a normal blog with an image for each post in the homepage, and then the post page with the rest of the photoset..is it possible to say in HTML a conditional tag which would say : If is_home you show the first image of the photoset, else you show the photoset?

I tried to install other themes, but everytime i see the post on the homepage with the whole photoset...

Answer (score 0):

OK this is how I would do it. Most themes have jquery installed, you need to make sure yours does. In fact it does I just checked.

I would create two variables like this inside an iframe load function (as tumblr embeds photosets in iframes by default):

```
 $('iframe.photoset').load(function(){
     $path = window.location.pathname;
     $primaryDir = $path.split("/")[1];
        if(($primaryDir == 'page') || (!$primaryDir)){
           $iframe = $('iframe.photoset').contents();
           $iframe.find('.photoset_row:gt(0)').remove();
        }
 });
```

The variable $path just returns the current url, $primaryDir splits the url at the leading / and gets the first index (page, about, tagged, etc)

Then we need an if statement to test the variables. If the primary directory is nothing, or 'page' then run this function.

Now the next bit might be a bit tricky for me to get the right selector. We need to find the photoset element and remove any image that is not the first one, this is embedded in an iframe, so we need this to run outside of the document ready function.

I think that will work, but it will need some testing and tweaking.

(I've made loads of edits to this so apologies if it is not clear.

Comment: wow, thanks lharby, i don't really know how to customize jquery for tumblr, but i'll be looking for it. I thought it was simplier :( :(

Comment: I am more used to that way of working, I think if you found someone with advanced tumblr templating knowledge, they might be able to do it, but that is not my forte! Good luck, give me a shout if it's not working.